# How to scan a system?

Tags: mass-effect

I am playing with Mass Effect 1. I am in the Strenuus system, a person called Garoth asked me to find his brother's ship. I read that I should scan for it, but I don't know how to do that. I cannot see a scan option on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to scan a system for the ship, but rather the ship will be on the galaxy map when you are in the same system as it. According to the [Mass Effect wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/UNC:_Privateers), the ship is located in

> the Strenuus system of the Horse Head Nebula

Comment: Yepp I have found it hidden on the map. Thx.